# Using mega (=10^6) when writing by hand?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I just solved a problem which had answer 1.7*10^6 m (m=meters)

If I wanted to write this using M=10^6 it would be 1.7 Mm, which if I write it by hand would look like "1.7 mm" which is confusing. Is there a convention for this?

Comment: why would it look like "1.7mm" if you wrote it by hand? Why can't you write "1.7Mm"?

Comment: @danimal: If I write quickly in an exam for example

Comment: if you know there's ambiguity ahead, make sure you don't rush with your handwriting - make the upper case M larger and pointier than the lower case m

Comment: The capital M *is* the convention.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Thanks. I thought there might be "Me" or something but that would be too chemistryish.

Comment: Years ago as a student it quickly became evident that H was overloaded, between Hamiltonians, magnetism, and thermodynamics.  I consciously chose specific, stylized forms to use for each, and after several weeks it became automatic. As for meters vs mm vs Mm, I might just stick with scientific notation for most situations, and millimeters for a few relevant cases.

Comment: If you find you need to alter your handwriting somewhat to avoid those kinds of ambiguities, you will not be the first nor the last.

Comment: If you search the web a bit you can find the ISO guide to notation, which covers questions like this in great detail.  For example, Mm is ok, and M is million while m is one-thousandth (e.g. mm for millimeter);  K is Kelvins and k is thousand, never use Km for kilometer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's asking how to use good hand-writing in the case where you're too lazy to use good hand-writing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - were you able to find a free copy of the ISO-80000 guide? I could only find a ridiculously expensive one...

Comment: @Floris -- I'll try to find my old link.  THere's an identical book put out by NIST which may be easier to get hold of.  As a last resort,  I could email you the document

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I'd appreciate it if you could find a link that works. Thanks.

Comment: @Floris this the link  http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks! I was happy to see that big-E notation was actually used in that NIST document - they use it when expressing conversion factors (appendix B, page 40 onwards in your link). And I learnt that a statute mile is not quite the same thing as a mile (there is a factor 0.999 998 between them because of a change made in 1959. The things you learn...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two conventions.

First - use a capital M - make sure you make it big and pointy, so it cannot be confused with lower case:

[image]

When it is right next to the lower case 'm', the difference should stand out clearly.

Second - some people use the "computer short hand" E6:

## 1.7E6 m

This is generally understood to mean (but quicker to write than) $1.7\cdot 10^{6}\mathrm{\;m}$, but more often used with a keyboard than when written by hand - and it can lead to confusion (see for example Rob's comment - who has seen that some students appear to think that 1.23e6 = $1.23 \cdot e^{6} \approx 496$). Note that using a capital $E$ as opposed to a lower-case $e$ *ought* to reduce the confusion... but when things are open to misinterpretation, *somebody* will misinterpret. And the consequences *can* be significant.

If all else fails, take the extra second and write the exponential in full. Time taken to communicate your intention clearly is invariably time well spent. This is true in exams as in life.

Comment: Thanks, I really like the E notation. I'll double check with the exam board to see if they accept it.

Comment: "When in doubt, spell it out!". And good luck with the exams. Let us know what they say - if you hear back from them.

Comment: "Computer shorthand" is discouraged if you are not a computer, or recording numbers for computer input.

Comment: @rob - who is discouraging it? While I don't prefer it, I think that clarity of communication is key - and these days, when you are communicating among scientists who use computers intensively, I don't think such notation leads to misunderstanding. Although in hand written notes I think the time saved is truly minimal, I for one don't discourage it. But I do take note of the two downvotes this answer got - clearly the community is divided on the issue.

Comment: @Floris *I* discourage it :) I looked for a little while and couldn't find reference to big-E notation in the style guides for APS, AMA, Science, and Nature; those publications all use "standard" scientific notation. I've *never* seen big-E notation in a physics publication that had an editor involved. The intro physics textbook by Halliday et al. mentions big-E notation as something used "on computers," then never uses it again. What's more, I have had students who reached university believing that "1.23e6" means $1.23\exp 6 \approx 496.$ I would discourage it more if I had space in this box.

Comment: @rob - fair point. I was wondering if you knew of an "authoritative discouragement" (not that I don't consider you an authority!). I am going to modify my answer to take your discouragment into account. As for comment about 1.23e6 - that is astounding and sad.

Comment: @Floris Well, my students know differently after leaving my class; I try not to fault gen-ed students entering science classes with a deficit of science knowledge. I actually found big-E notation in the IEEE style guide, but their journals are very computer-heavy. There might be official guidance in ISO-31 or ISO-80000, but I'm not going to pay for a copy of the standards to find out.

Comment: @rob, I tried looking at the ISO-80000 guide, and found a price tag of 156 Swiss Francs... like you, I said to myself "never mind, I didn't want to know the answer that badly".

Comment: @rob - the [NIST guidance on SI notation](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf) uses big-E notation in their table of conversion factors (see page 40 onwards in the linked doc). That gives at least some credence to my assertion that "it is done" - even though I agree it is not desirable. Key to communication is "does my audience understand what I mean". If they do, you succeeded. If they don't, it doesn't matter how many references back up your style.

Answer (score 2):

People who work with neutrons frequently find themselves discussing mega-electronvolts (MeV, typical nuclear energy) and milli-electronvolts (meV, typical room-temperature thermal energy) in the same sentence. It is mostly not a problem to use MeV and meV when writing. When speaking, some people will say "big em ee vee" or "little em ee vee", or pronounce mega- or milli- similarly to how I spelled them out above.

For what it's worth, I much more commonly hear "thousands of kilometers" than "millions of meters"; I can't recall the last time I heard someone discuss a length in mega-meters. Maybe it's the remnant effect of hundreds of poetic phrases involving "a thousand miles" to set the scale for that distance.